# Do rubyists reference accessors from mixins?

Tags: ruby, mixins

Is it considered bad practice to reference accessors on the extended object from within a mixin method? A simplistic example:

```
module WindInstrument
  def play
    mouthpiece.blow  #requires a mouthpiece
  end
end

class Saxophone
  attr_reader :mouthpiece

  def initialize
    @mouthpiece = Mouthpiece.new
  end

  include WindInstrument
end

Saxophone.new.play
```

In this case, I would actually just move the requirement for a mouthpiece directly to the WindInstrument module, but what about in a more complex scenario, where it really makes sense for the accessor to live on the extended object? Is this just an issue of an inappropriate separation of concerns?

Mixins feel useful for adding encapsulated behavior that doesn't require knowledge of the extended object's state. In fact, my gut tells me that a mixin shouldn't have knowledge of any state, whatsoever. If it needs knowledge of state, I would typically fall back to one of two choices:

- **Put the state in a class, and add it through composition, instead of through the inheritance hierarchy.** My issue with this is that I *know* rubyists out there are creating mixins that access state, which makes for more readable, if less intuitive (to me) design.
- **Pass the mouthpiece as a parameter to the module.** Even I can tell that this seems to muddy the design, and feels like an abomination in the ruby worldview.

Does this code bother anyone else? I know there are a lot of smart people using ruby out there, so I assume the problem is mine. What am I missing? Do I just need to chill out? What would *you* do?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same as in monkey-patching: it's ok to do it, but you have to make sure that there are no alternatives first (ie. You can't modify the classes using your interface) and second, you must be very explicit about it (make sure that the docs, the comments and the interface mention that this our that method is required and will be invoked) and throw a useful error message if it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's accessors are interfaces, not implementation.

For example, if you call `person.height_in_feet=`, you don't know what units the height is actually implemented in as an instance variable. It could be metres, feet, or cubits.

One real-life example of mixins using an accessor is the `Enumerable` module. Although I don't include this module in any classes I create, I'm happy with what it does. It gives you convenient methods like `map` and `each_with_index`, while staying DRY - there's only one implementation of what objects you'd access with all of the methods of the "mixee", and there's only one definition of what `map` does, for any object that uses `Enumerable`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I get that the accessors are interfaces. I'm more concerned with the case where a module knows about the interface of the object it's extending. I'll update my post to include a clear example.